# How to get div tag content with regex

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing

i want to get div tag's content.
For example:

```
<div id="gameDetailsInner">
<div id="headerText" style="padding-left: 0px !important;padding-top: 0px !important;">
<h1><a href="http://www.abc.com/games.php?flash=7264">abc text</a></h1>
</div>
<div style="min-height: 90px;">
<a href="http://www.abc.com/games.php?param=12345"><img src="http://abc.abc.com/images/7264.jpg" alt="abc" width="120" height="78" id="gameDetailsInnerImg"/>
</a>
How can i get this text with regex?
</div>
```

Thanks...

Comment: Why do you need regex? Are you trying to parse a static HTML document? If so, what language are you working in?

Comment: @AndyLester you can, you shouldn't :)

Comment: Yes I'm trying to parse a static HTML document,I am using c # :\

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289440/cannot-get-regular-expression-work-correctly-with-multiline (in C#)

Comment: I will not recommend regex in parsing HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in PHP, you can use the `strip_tags()` function to remove all HTML tags from a string.

Anything more than that, you need to use a proper HTML parser.  You can't parse HTML with regular expressions. You need to use a proper HTML parser. http://htmlparsing.com lists a number of solutions for different languages.

Comment: @ÖzkanSelek I tagged your question with the c# tag.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't reliably parse HTML using a Regex.  Please see this famous question for details: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div.*>([^>]+)</div>
```

**Group1** gives the content of the `div` if the content is just before the end `</div>`