# Yet Another MultiLine Group Regex Query

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So I'm trying to write a regex to filter text files for specific snippets (looking for speed rather than brute force).

I want to get three things from each match:

- a **key** to identify a snippet
- an optional **language** to format each snippet
- the **value** which represents all rows between the start and end tags

This is the regex (a failing test harness can be found here - https://gist.github.com/shiftkey/5236161):

`(?s)code start (?<key>[A-Za-z-]*) (?<language>[A-Za-z]*).*[\n](?<value>.*?)[\n].*end code (?<key>[A-Za-z-]*)`

Using these options: `RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Multiline`.

So a file like this:

```
// code start foo csharp
var x = 1;
// end code foo
```

Gives me the expected values:

- **key**: foo
- **language**: csharp
- **value**: `var x = 1;`

But when I introduce a snippet with a second row I only get the last row:

```
// code start foo csharp
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
// end code foo
```

- **key**: foo
- **language**: csharp
- **value**: `var y = 2;`

Instead of

- **value**: `var x = 1;\r\nvar y = 2;` (or similar)

What have I missed with getting groups to cover multiple lines?

I've looked at similar scenarios raised on SO but they haven't worked for my usage.

Comment: Use SingleLine instead Multiline to "." to match "\n"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289440/cannot-get-regular-expression-work-correctly-with-multiline

Comment: I want to parse just about any sort of text file - not just XML. I could do the sample in C# or ruby or any language which has comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be worked-around by changing the greediness of two `.*`s:

```
(?s)code start (?<key>[A-Za-z-]*) (?<language>[A-Za-z]*).*?[\n](?<value>.*)[\n].*?end code (?<key>[A-Za-z-]*)
```

The `.*` after reading the language must be less greedy, because we need the content after the first new-line as the snippet value. However, the `.*` for parsing `value` can be more greedy, because it's not supposed to stop upon meeting the first `\n`, hence the above pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can do the catch with some lookaround stuff as well...

```
(?<=code\sstart\s)(?<key>\b\w+\b)\s(?<language>\b\w+\b).*\r\n(?<content>(?s).*)(?=\r\n.*end\scode\s\1\s-->)
```

Comment: I've got a more whitespace-tolerant version handy, but I'm also looking to support whatever text files have comments. So looking for the XML open/close comment tags won't help me in this case.

Comment: Could always skip the open/close tags if needed :) Thought you wanted it to be strict :P