# Web scraper using regular expression is working but not completely

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to scrape an HTML webpage using regular expressions.  Two of the three `MatchCollection`s work, but the third one does not.  I'm getting what i need from `match` and `match_id`, but when it comes to `match_price`, there is no result.

Can someone kindly tell me what is wrong?

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
string s = wb.DownloadString(@"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\html pages\hi.html");
        MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(s, "span class=\"\".*?</span>");
        MatchCollection match_id = Regex.Matches(s, "span class=\"product_id\".*?</span>");
        MatchCollection match_price = Regex.Matches(s, "div class=\"col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 align-right\".*?</div>");

foreach (Match m in match)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(m);
}

foreach (Match m in match_id)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(m);
}

foreach(Match m in match_price)
{
    listBox3.Items.Add(m);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/289451/3832970

Comment: This seems to work.  Can you post an example of the HTML that you are trying to match?

Comment: *"I'm trying to scrape an HTML webpage using regular expressions."* Why? Use an HTML parser.